# laravel 8 Sending smtp email using gmail fails with current settings

Tags: php, laravel, email, ssl, smtp

I want to send email using smtp with my laravel 8 project. I have an example project in which this works. Using this configuration in my current project is unsuccessful.

I am unable to use the example 1 one 1 because the folderstructure is different. My example uses the default laravel folder structure, my current project has a modular layout in which each folder represents an entity that has its own controllers, models etc. I have been on it for a while and would appreciate outside advice in order to get it working.

- The **'allow less secure apps'** option is enabled in gmail.
- The content of my **test_mail.blade.php** file is just some basic html.

**Mail function** is called from inside update function for convenience.
Frontend::email.test_mail , this points to a view that is in the same entity folder.
The example uses: /folder/subfolder/view, the rest of it is the same as the example.

```
$data = array("name"=>"testname", "employee_nr"=>"010" );
$subject = 'test_message';
$to_email = 'realtargetaddress@gmail.com';

Mail::send('Frontend::email.test_mail',$data, function($message) use( $to_email,$subject)
{
$message->to($to_email)->subject($subject);
$message->from($to_email,$subject);
});
```

configuration of **.env** file. (exact copy from example)

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465 # 587 for tls - 456 for ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=some_address@gmail.com
MAIL_USERNAME=some_address@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl  # tls or ssl
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

**config/mail.php** (also a exact copy from my example)

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

'from' => [
'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 
'hello@example.com'),
'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],

'markdown' => [
'theme' => 'default',
'paths' => [
resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
],
],
'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
```

**Mail.php** extends Facade
This class is in the Illuminate\Support\Facades namespace.
My example uses mail.manager in the getFacadeAccessor() method, which fails in my current project.
Using *mailer* instead of *mail.manager* does not produce errors but also does not work.

**console commands** that used after making changes to .env

- php artisan config:clear
- php artisan config:cache
- php artisan cache:clear

**edit** The error that this gives me is:
Unable to resolve NULL driver for [Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager].
I searched with that but did not find a fix.

**solution** I was adviced to add the following code to **mail.php**, make sure to add it on top and to run the console commands. After i did this the mail function worked for me.

```
 'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],
    ],
```